# Using LINQ to XML with xml response from SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, t-sql, linq-to-xml

I'm having a problem with LINQ TO XML and XMLReader.
The problem is that i can't load the XMLReader response into the LINQ Object and getting empty object all the time and Object no set to an instance of an object exception.

CODE:

```
XmlReader xDr = SqlHelper.ExecuteXmlReader(
                                            new SqlConnection(ConnectionString),
                                            CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                                            "SP"
                                           );



XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(xDr);
            var Jobs = from Job in xDoc.Descendants("Job")
                       select new {...}
```

I now i am getting the xml from the server into the XmlReader, but when i am looking at the xDoc object, it is empty....

Can any one help with this?

Thank you,
Erez

Comment: can you show us the XML you get from this SP please (preferably by debugging and getting it's value as a string at runtime)

Comment: is the xml returned a complete, valid xml document? does the code work if you use `XElement` instead of `XDocument`?

Comment: Thank you, and sorry but i can't show that data, the structure is: <Jobs><Job attr1="" attr2=""....><Region></Regions<cities></cities></Job><Job attr1="" attr2=""....><Region></Regions<cities></cities></Job><Job attr1="" attr2=""....><Region></Regions<cities></cities></Job><User attr1="" attr2="">...</User></Jobs> Hope this helps, thank you

Comment: The code works if i user xmlDocument or xPathDocument but i want to use LINQ-TO-XML...I mean the query work and i can read data from it

Comment: try `XElement element = XElement.Load(xDr)`

Comment: I don't know whether it's a typo, but there is a > missing off the end of Regions in the xml above, and `<Region>` does not match `</Regions>`

Comment: typo, 10x...The XML is OK, checked and rechecked it

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer....Sorry guys, The problem was not in the loading, that is the result i got, but the problem was in some of the attributes in the XML that i missed noticing that where missing in some of the jobs....

Now every thing is working.

Thank you,
Erez